# Add lines indicating quartiles to a scatterplot

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I have to plot  lines on a scatterplot at each quartile of a bivariate distribution. I plotted the scatterplot in this way:

```
plot (data1, data2, col = "blue")
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: do you mean a bivariate distribution?  something like `abline(v=quantile(data1,c(0.25,0.5,0.75)); abline(h=quantile(data2,c(0.25,0.5,0.75))` **might** do what you want, but you haven't made it very clear ...

Comment: Not quite sure why you deleted this question -- it wasn't totally clear, but it seems like a reasonable question, and better to let the answer stand if it's going to be useful to someone in the future ...

Comment: ok, I deleted this question because probably is very basic!

Answer (score 4):

(Comment reposted as answer.)

Do you mean a bivariate distribution? something like

```
abline(v=quantile(data1,c(0.25,0.5,0.75)))
abline(h=quantile(data2,c(0.25,0.5,0.75)))
```

might do what you want, but you haven't made it very clear ...